# Code gives no errors and runs, but fails on archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this code in a function that is part of Firebase Remote Config.  The issue isn't a Firebase issue as my code runs in simulator and on devices, but when I archive the same code it throw errors.

I have tried all sorts of combinations to get this to work...any help is appreciated.

```
    [[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig] fetchWithExpirationDuration:0 completionHandler:^(FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus status, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        [[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig] activateFetched];
        [self updateData];
    }
}];
```

[image: Screenshot of the "errors"]

Comment: i think the problem is `expirationTime = 43200.0` is missing `;`. it not executed on debug, so there are no error, it is only executed on release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forget to add `;` at the end of `expirationTime = 43200.0`.

Since you prepro it with `#ifdef DEBUG #else`, the code was not executed on debug mode, so there was no error when you run it on debug mode,

**General Suggestion** for anyone who came here with the problem of *"working build on debug mode, but not on release mode"*, first try to search if there are `#ifdef DEBUG` prepro, and make sure that there are no error on the *other side* of `#ifdef DEBUG`

Comment: your welcome @user3534305, please don't be, it's a common mistake that everyone can make, even someone experienced